# Puppeteer when error go to previous function or call

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i want to make a pupeteer script that if the page is error or in some case facing a connection issues for example "Aw Snap!" in chrome my script will reload/refresh/navigate to the original destination target url. so in .catch() command have to call some refresh/re-navigate function. for now i only can show text message when catch an error with console.log. here's my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({headless:false}).then(async browser => {  
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.on('error',async err => {console.log('on page.on');});

await page.goto('https://www.google.com').then(async ()=> {
    while(1){
    await page.waitForSelector("img",{timeout:7000})
        .then(async () => {             
            await page.evaluate(() => {                 
                return document.querySelector('div.jsb input[name="btnI"]').value;  

                }).then(abc => {
                    console.log(abc);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('input button not found!!'));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('selector not found!!'));         
    }   
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));            

});
```

so what i want is :

when 'input button not found!!' it mean something happen to the google page either connection issue or something. i need to re-visit url https://www.google.com when 'input button not found!!' triggered. How to do that? i don't want to manually write it twice by replacing text 'input button not found!!' into `await page.goto('https://www.google.com')`

what i want is dynamic solution like placing some function() , etc

Thank you.